# AngularJS UI-Grid row.entity nested JSON

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

How can I get the row.entity values from a JSON file with multiple levels?

```
{date: 20-09-2022,
            adType: [{
                    type: staff,
                    adCount: [{
                            count: 7
                    }]
            }, {
                    type: start,
                    adCount: [{
                            count: 9
                    }]
            }]
},

 {date: 21-09-2022,
            adType: [{
                    type: staff,
                    adCount: [{
                            count: 7
                    }]
            }, {
                    type: start,
                    adCount: [{
                            count: 9
                    }]
            }]
 }
```

When I do a {{row.entity[adType]}} in my cellTemplate, I can get this string

```
**[{type: "staff", adCount: Array(1)},{type: "start", adCount: Array(1)}]**
```

However row.entity[adType].type do not return anything.

So how can I go deeper to get the count: 7?

Answer (score 0):

Here {{row.entity[adType]}} --> is array type. So if you want to get the count result as 7, then You can use **{{row.entity[adType][0].adCount[0].count}}**

Comment: Do you know how i can get the row index dynamically for this using ui-grid.